# Passing a Pointer into a Function and Modifying it

Tags: c++, function, pointers

New to both stackoverflow and C/C++.  Im working through implementing a binary tree and have a simple question.  Lets say I have the following:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* right_child;
    Node* left_child;
};

void addNode(Node* tree, int new_data){
    if(tree == NULL){
        Node* new_tree = new Node;
        new_tree->data = new_data;
        new_tree->right_child = NULL;
        new_tree->left_child = NULL;
        tree = new_tree;
    }
}

int main(){
    Node* tree = new Node;
    tree = NULL;
    addNode(tree, 3);
    cout << tree->data << endl; //CRASH
}
```

Pretty simple right.  It would crash because the tree would still be NULL, even after the return from addNode.  what I have attempted to understand is why it would not be updated once addNode is called.  Sure, a copy of the pointer is used and updated, but shouldn't it still hold the same address?  Therefore, still update the original memory address and return.  Or does the new pointer for some reason point to a different location?  I'm confused about what is going on.  Any help would be wonderful.

Also, i just wrote that code on the website - sorry if there are little errors, didnt actually run it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you setting `tree` to NULL right after initializing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems,

First, you have a local copy of the pointer `addNode`, and you are not de-referencing it to act on the thing it points to, but acting directly on the local pointer itself. The `new`ed `Node` created inside the function is just lost forever.

You can fix that problem by passing the pointer by reference. This doesn't require any other modifications to your code:

```
void addNode(Node*& tree, int new_data)
```

Second, as you noted, you are de-referencing a NULL pointer in `main`. This is simply *undefined behaviour* (UB). One of the things that can happen is a crash. But the code could just run silently without crashing too. The important fact is that is it UB and the program cannot be relied on.

**Note 1**: If you want to initialize your `Node`s such that the data members are zero initialized, use *value initialization*:

```
Node* tree = new Node();
```

**Note 2**: Be very careful with using raw `new`ed pointers. You already have <strike>one</strike> **two** resource leaks in your code. Better use the most appropriate type of smart pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Due to that you pass the pointer to tree in addNode

```
void addNode(Node* tree, int new_data)
```

the statement

```
tree = new_tree;
```

will only be local, you are not changing what the passed pointer is pointing to since tree is a copy of the pointer.

compare with

```
void foo(int n) {  n = 1; }   // local, n is a copy
void foo(int* n) { *n = 1; }  // change the original variabel
```

in order to change what tree points to you need to pass the address of the pointer

```
void addNode(Node** tree, int new_data)
{
...
   *tree = new Node;
...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep the changes reflected in your main function(for a pointer or a non pointer variable), the secure way is pass it by reference, because reference variables can be initialized only once

i.e :

```
void addNode(Node*& tree, int new_data)
{
   Node* tree_1;

   tree = &tree_1 //this can't be done
}

void addNode(Node** tree, int new_data)
{
   Node* tree_1;

   tree = &tree_1 //this can be done
}
```

So the safest way is to pass by reference, i mean `void addNode(Node*& tree, int new_data)`

Comment: It is true that references can only be initialized once, but that is also true of everything else. In any case, the line marked "this can't be done" can actually be done. Passing by reference is the fix OP needs, as explained in my answer.

Comment: Can you please compile a sample code? for the first addNode function, the compiler says Error '=' : cannot convert from 'Node **' to 'Node *'

Comment: can you please run the same as mine void addNode(Node*& tree, int new_data)
{
   Node* tree_1;

   tree = &tree_1 //this can't be done
}

Comment: please, i meant f = &tmp; not f = tmp;

Comment: Ah OK, I didn't see that. It actually doesn't make any sense, and has nothing to do with references. You are trying to assign a `Node**` to a `Node*`.